# Getting error "NameError: name 'newaxis' is not defined" when adding a new column to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example:

```
#Creating a new empty dataframe
test=pd.DataFrame()

test_list=[1,3,5,6,3,1]

#Now I am converting this list to a dataframe column
test["Test name"]=test_list
```

After executing the last line of code I am getting this error:

> NameError: name 'newaxis' is not defined

Comment: Is it all your programme? Show your import lines please. May be your installation of numpy is broken, I'm not sure

Comment: @SAURABH RANA check my answer please, and if it's not correct - show the full log of the error, please.

Comment: @SAURABH RANA if my answer satisfies you - I'll be thankful if you can mark it as the correct answer. If it's not correct - feel free to ask for any improvements - I'll be glad to help you.
You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, that you are using double-quotation marks properly?

That's one of the ways I'm able to reproduce your error:

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.DataFrame()

test_list=[1,3,5,6,3,1]

test[newaxis]=test_list
```

And the problem here is that you need to have double-quotation marks on newaxis since it should be a string:

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.DataFrame()

test_list=[1,3,5,6,3,1]

test["newaxis"]=test_list
```

Or, if your `newaxis` is a variable - then you have to define it:

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.DataFrame()

test_list=[1,3,5,6,3,1]

newaxis = 'column_name'

test[newaxis]=test_list
```

Also - it's possible, that you have an error related to another part of your code, for example, you are trying to use `numpy.newaxis`, but you call it just `newaxis` instead of `numpy.newaxis`. More information about error needed here.

Comment: Do you mean *double-quotation marks* with *parentheses*?

Comment: Yes.
You have to pass the string to:

`df[some_string] = some list`

And it seems, like the value you're trying to pass instead of `some_string` - is just an undefined variable.